# Proving inequality with complex variables by using linear mappings

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, inequality, complex-numbers

I'm following the book **A First Course in Complex Analysis with Applications** to self-learn about complex analysis (feel free to recommend any other book that you think could be better than this one).

There are 2 exercises in point 2.3 (Complex Functions and Mappings: Linear Mappings) that I'm having a bit of trouble solving (I have in general some issues with linear mappings, but I'm starting and managing). The 2 exercises are:

---

***Exercise 1*** (Exercise 37)

Justify the inequality $|(1+i)z - 2| \leq 2 + \sqrt{2} $ for $|z| \leq |1|$ using linear mappings.

*What I tried:*
Geometrically speaking, this linear mapping implies rotating the circle $\frac{\pi}{2}$, magnify by $\sqrt{2}$ and translate by $-2$ in the real axis. The furthest point given this circumstance is the one of the circles which is cut by a line that goes from the center to the origin (which in this case is the real axis), and so, that point is the one of the real axes at a distance of $2 + \sqrt{2}$

---

***Exercise 2*** (Exercise 38)

Consider the complex function $f(z) = 2iz + 1 - i$ defined on the closed annulus $2 \leq |z| \leq 3$. Use linear mappings to determine upper and lower on the modulus of $f(z)$.

There are more sections but this is the one that interests me.

*What I tried:* I did something similar to the previous exercise, analyzing what this function does(turn $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians, magnify by 2, and translate from the original $1+i$), but I wasn't able to do much more. I thought of doing a similar thing, and the solution would be found (this is, in this case, this line would go through the origin and have a slope of $-\frac{\pi}{4}$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> You're essentially done; on the second exercise, how close is the transformed annulus from $0$, and how far? A little more precisely, what's the radius of the largest disk about $0$ that is disjoint from the transformed annulus, and the radius of the smallest disk containing the transformed annulus? <> In case it's helpful, the analytic approach to these types of question is the triangle inequality $|z \pm w| \leq |z| + |w|$ for upper bounds, and the reverse triangle inequality $\bigl||z| - |w|\bigr| \leq |z \pm w|$ for lower bounds.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you very much for the answer and for welcoming me! I will try using the triangle inequalities to solve the problems then! there is only an issue with that (at least in the first exercise). It says that it should be done without using the triangle inequality. For that reason, I would like to know which would be the formal answer to this, since more or less my answer solves the problem, but I don't see it as a formal answer to it.

Comment: My guess (not knowing the book) is, the author is looking for the geometric arguments you've found, i.e., those are rigorous enough. :)

Comment: Your rotation angles are wrong. $1+i = \sqrt 2 e^{i\pi/4}$ and $2i = 2 e^{i\pi/2}$, so the rotations are by $\frac \pi 4$ and $\frac \pi 2$ respectively. But since in each case you are rotating a set with circular symmetry, the angle of the rotation doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: @PaulSinclair true, my mistake, fast tipping in this case. Thank you, I will edit!

Comment: For the 2nd question, you are on the right track (though the center is $1-i$). Because the set has circular symmetry, the maximum and minimum moduli of $f(z)$ will occur on the line from the origin through the center. The center is at a distance of $\sqrt 2$, and the outer radius is $6$ while the inner radius is $4$. So, rotate the set to move the center to the real line. Rotations about $0$ do not change the modulus, so the answer is still the same. The center is at $\sqrt 2$, and the line intersects the annulus in intervals $[4+ \sqrt 2, 6 + \sqrt 2]$ and $[\sqrt 2 - 4, \sqrt 2 - 6]$